# AppEngine Launcher 1.9.23 is slow on OSX

Tags: google-app-engine

Has anyone else noticed that the latest AppEngine Launcher, version 1.9.23, takes a lot longer to deploy code?  What used to take less than a minute now takes over 15 minutes.  Is there something I can do to fix this?

Here's the console output for a single-file push (out of 100 files total):

```
*** Running appcfg.py with the following flags:
    --oauth2_credential_file=~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens update
07:26 AM Application: ******; version: 1
07:26 AM Host: appengine.google.com
07:26 AM 
Starting update of app: ******, version: 1
07:26 AM Getting current resource limits.
07:28 AM Scanning files on local disk.
Could not guess mimetype for media/ng-ckeditor.min.map.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/ng-ckeditor.min.map.  Using application/octet-stream.
07:29 AM Cloning 48 static files.
07:31 AM Cloning 49 application files.
07:32 AM Uploading 1 files and blobs.
07:33 AM Uploaded 1 files and blobs.
07:33 AM Compilation starting.
07:35 AM Compilation completed.
07:35 AM Starting deployment.
07:36 AM Checking if deployment succeeded.
07:37 AM Deployment successful.
07:38 AM Checking if updated app version is serving.
07:40 AM Completed update of app: ******, version: 1
07:41 AM Uploading index definitions.
If deploy fails you might need to 'rollback' manually.
The "Make Symlinks..." menu option can help with command-line work.
*** appcfg.py has finished with exit code 0 ***
```

Comment: Hey Brent. I must say I haven't heard any reports about something like this since 1.9.23 was released. If you can reliably reproduce (maybe give a test with 1.9.22 as well to compare), then posting on our issue tracker might be the best course of action (code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues), if you include some information about your config, your OS, exactly what you're using to push, etc etc.

Comment: Where can I find 1.9.22?

Comment: From https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads, you have a link to the older ones. Seems like 1.9.22 isn't in the older list, but tests from 1.9.21 would do fine as well :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/